# Fallback image when autoplay doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, safari, autoplay

I'm developing my portfolio using React and Gatsby and I am using a video to create an animated shadow. The video is in autoplay and works fine using *autoplay, muted* and *playsinline* tags However the animation doesn't play on Safari when Low Power Mode is on.

[Animation playing (low power mode off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8eqh.gif)

[Animation not playing (low power mode on)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1NPb.png)

I know that Apple blocks the video in order to save battery but as I can see on their website, particularly on their Pro Display XDR (https://www.apple.com/pro-display-xdr/), they use a fallback image when the video can't play. I wanted to know what was the best way to make the same thing using React?

Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `poster` attribute in your video tag.

```html
<video width="250" height="250" playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="https://via.placeholder.com/250&text=I%20am%20Poster">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm"
            type="video/webm">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

No Source or failed video:

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop width="250" height="250" poster="https://via.placeholder.com/250&text=I%20am%20Poster">
    <source src="#"
            type="video/webm">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your feedback! I already tried the poster method but I'm looking for something else because it stills load the video (it shows the play button). I'd like it to be like : if low power mode = true then image else video